# MySQL Left Join not showing rows from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables. 1 table shows location information, and another shows wifi ssids and passwords for the location. These tables are joined by a column 'LocationID'. The reason for the 2 separate tables is so that I can keep a historical trail of ssids and passwords for a specific location.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT Location.LocationID,
    Location.SystemName,
    Location.SiteNameLocation,
    Location.SiteAddress1,
    Location.SiteAddress2,
    Location.SiteCity,
    Location.SiteProvince,
    Location.SitePostalCode,
    Location.ContactName,
    Location.ContactPhone, 
    Location.ContactEmail,
    Location.ID1POC,
    Location.ID2District,
    Location.SiteLocationHours,
    LocationWiFi.WiFiSSID,
    LocationWiFi.WiFiPassphrase,
    LocationWiFi.WiFiDate
    FROM Location
    LEFT JOIN LocationWiFi ON LocationWiFi.LocationID = Location.LocationID
```

What I need to do is obtain the most recent wifi ssid and passphrase from the table to show it with the corresponding locationID

I can do it with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM LocationWiFi WHERE WiFiDate = (SELECT MAX(WiFiDate) FROM LocationWiFi) AND LocationID = xxxx
```

I am sure it isnt that hard, I just can not quite figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT...

Sorry for the confusion here everyone. let me try and be more clear. I have 1500+ entrys in location table. 2 entries in LocationWiFi table with the same locationid. I need the first query (the one with the join) to return all 1500+ rows, but only pull the wifi ssid and password with the max date. For the locations that do not have wifi ssid and passphrase, i simply want to show the column with a null value.

Again I apologize

***SOLUTION***

Hi Everyone,

I have solved this issue. For anyone who is having a similar solution, here is what worked for me.

```
SELECT Location.LocationID,
    Location.SystemName,
    Location.SiteNameLocation,
    Location.SiteAddress1,
    Location.SiteAddress2,
    Location.SiteCity,
    Location.SiteProvince,
    Location.SitePostalCode,
    Location.ContactName,
    Location.ContactPhone, 
    Location.ContactEmail,
    Location.ID1POC,
    Location.ID2District,
    Location.SiteLocationHours,
    a.WiFiSSID,
    a.WiFiPassphrase
    FROM Location
    LEFT JOIN(
SELECT LocationWiFi.WiFiSSID,
           LocationWiFi.WiFiPassphrase,
           LocationWiFi.LocationID
FROM LocationWiFi
WHERE LocationWiFi.WiFiDate = (SELECT MAX(WiFiDate) FROM LocationWiFi)
    ) AS a
    ON a.LocationID = Location.LocationID;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If you can do it with that query, then what is your question about?

Comment: better where clausule: `ORDER BY WiFiDate DESC LIMIT 1` (if column has correct type - timestamp, datetime, etc)

Comment: Is this a trick question?you can do it from as single table and than you ask for a join?

Comment: Corey wants to use a join rather than a subquery as a subquery isn't as efficient. Admittedly, its not explained very well in the original post.

Comment: @Corey Stadnyk, are you able to get any data from LocationWifi in the first query? Is LocationID the same field in both tables? Are you getting any errors? Answers to these questions would be helpful to solving your problem. You should also clarify better in your post what you're trying to do.

Comment: No. I need to first query to return 1500+ rows but i need it to only select wifi ssid and password with the max date. Do you understand

Comment: You shouldn't update your question to include the solution. If one of the given answers is correct for you, you should accept it as the best. If neither of the answers are entirely correct, you should post your solution as an answer and select *that* as the best. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2725/213634) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59172/213634) or related questions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The following query is more efficient since it is not using a sub query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM LocationWiFi 
WHERE LocationID = xxxx
ORDER BY WiFiDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is a better query than the second one Corey posted, but its not what he's looking for. If this query were to be used, it would have to be run for EVERY Location returned in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

You had everything you needed, just have to put them together:

```
SELECT l.*, lw.*
FROM Location l
JOIN LocationWifi lw ON l.locationId= lw.locationId
WHERE lw.WiFiDate = (
  SELECT MAX(WiFiDate)
  FROM locationWifi
  WHERE locationId = l.locationId
);
```

It's subquery per row, but I don't think there is any good way around it.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/350ac/1